# whether the given statement is right or wrong

Tags: modal-verbs

> You can leave after you will finish the work.

Is this formation correct? The main clause is in present tense and the subordinate clause is in the future tense.

Comment: Hi Please use full words and complete sentences.  Where have you seen this sentence? did you write it? is it homework? did you read it somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

No, the sentence *You can leave after you will finish the work* is not grammatical.

In his entry on *after (conjunction)* Swan in *Practical English Usage* (p30) states:

> We use *after* with a present tense to talk about the future:
>
> - I'll telephone you after I arrive. (NOT ...after I will arrive)

He explains this principle in more depth in his section on *tense simplication in subordinate clauses* (p580):

> If the main clause of a sentence makes it clear what kind of time the
> speaker is talking about, it is not always necessary for the same time
> to be indicated again in subordinate clauses.  ... Verbs in
> subordinate clauses are often in simpler form than verbs in main
> clauses - for example, *present* instead of *future*.

In your example, the modal *can* is used in the present to express future permission. This is very common: *You can go* vs. *You will be permitted / able to go*.